# Ajax does not retrieves data in partial view in mvc 5 using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my HTML :

```
@model ModalPopupMVC.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("View All", "Index")

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtName" name="searchparam" placeholder="type here to search" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Search" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }

</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.location)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.emp1)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor (modelItem =>item.FName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.location)
            </td>
            <td>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchorDetail" data-id="@item.Entryid">
Details
</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<div id='myModal' class='modal'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here are my scripts :

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var TeamDetailPostBackURL = '/Home/Details';
    $(function () {
        $(".anchorDetail").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var $buttonClicked = $(this);
            var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
            var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { "Id": id },
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;

                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal(options);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
                }
            });
        });
        //$("#closebtn").on('click',function(){
        //    $('#myModal').modal('hide');

        $("#closbtn").click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    });

    </script>

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataAccess objda = new DataAccess();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            User emp = new User();
            emp.Action = 4000;
            ds = objda.getData(emp);

            var bList = new List<User>();
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    bList.Add(new User
                    {
                        Entryid = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                        sno = dr[0].ToString(),
                        FName = dr[2].ToString(),
                        LName = dr[3].ToString(),
                        location = dr[4].ToString(),
                        email = dr[5].ToString(),
                    });

                }
            }
            emp.emp1 = bList;
            return View("Index", emp);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Details(int Id)
        {
            User usr = new User();
            usr.Entryid = Id;
            usr.Action = 4002;
            ds = objda.getData(usr);

            var bList = new List<User>();
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    bList.Add(new User
                    {
                        Entryid = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                        sno = dr[0].ToString(),
                        FName = dr[2].ToString(),
                        LName = dr[3].ToString(),
                        location = dr[4].ToString(),
                        email = dr[5].ToString(),
                    });

                }
            }
            usr.emp1 = bList;
            return PartialView("_Details", usr);
        } 
}
```

// this is my partial view

```
<div>

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit User</h4>
    </div>
    @foreach (var MenuItem in Model.emp1)
    {
        <div class="modal-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "First name", @Value = MenuItem.FName, @Class = "editor-field" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FName)
                </div>

                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LName, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Last name", @Value = MenuItem.LName, @Class = "editor-field" } })
                </div>
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Email id", @Value = MenuItem.email, @Class = "editor-field" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
            </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.location, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Address", @Value = MenuItem.location, @Class = "editor-field" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.location)
                </div>

            }
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Save Changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

In my code, I am calling partial view with ajax, but when I click on the user details link, the description of that user is not retrieved through ajax and it shows a blank bootstrap modal popup.

I am retrieving the details of user selected by user on the same page but it is not retrieved. Please give any suggestion where is the issue because I am new to ASP.NET MVC 5.

Thanks

Comment: Start by removing `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and (your not stringifying the data) change it to `datatype: "html",` (your returning a view, not json)

Comment: Did you checked your action method by adding a breakpoint whether it is called or not. if called are you getting Id value?

Comment: did you got any errors in console. what response you see in using your dev tools in browser consose?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the url that you are constructing is incorrect. Try getting rid of `contentType`, `data` and `dataType` parameters and use an url of the form `{controller}/{action}/{id}` which is what I suppose your routing engine is configured to support:

```
var TeamDetailPostBackURL = '@Url.Action("Details", "Home")';
$(".anchorDetail").click(function () {
    debugger;
    var $buttonClicked = $(this);
    var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
    var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: TeamDetailPostBackURL + '/' + id,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;

            $('#myModalContent').html(data);
            $('#myModal').modal(options);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
        }
    });
});
```

Also use your browser developer toolbar to inspect the AJAX request that is being sent to the server and the actual response. This would allow you to more easily debug problems with your code.

Comment: I caught the mistake.Actually I did not apply foreach loop on my partial view ,that's why data is not rendered on my modal.

Comment: ** Now I am facing a new problem as I use jquery data table with searching , sorting and pagination at the first page of data table modal is popup properly but after changing the page the modal is not popup i.e. the JS for modal is not called on link click.Please help me out.**